# My javascript doesn't run in IE from first instance, but runs after I have Developer Tools opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an issue with JS. A slideshow with `.animate()`, which seems to work in every browser, except any version of IE. Here's a demo: http://mamar2.monline.dk/lindvedmarine/business.php

Can anyone see why this is?

Comment: There is an answer and good comments to your problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14683805/834309

Answer (score 2):

You probably call `console.log` which is provided by the IE developer tools and doesn't exist when the developer tools are not running.

Answer (score 2):

As i can see from the source code you have `console.log` statements in your script. If i am not wrong `console` does not exist in `IE` if developers tools are closed. So try to comment out those statements or use the script below.

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function noop() {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());
```

See your page source code from FF. You will see a few red lines and you will figure out that you don't open/close right your html. That has nothing to do with your question but maybe adds more problems in the feature.

Comment: Thank you @pbaris! That was quite helpful!

Obviously, my problem was with the html :)